# What's the relationship between the term "kernel call" and "system call"?

Tags: operating-system, system-calls

This question is originated from reading the famous book "Modern operating system" by Andrew S. Tanenbaum. I find that the writer use the term kernel call serveral times but never formally define it. And I think it's pretty similar to the term "system call", so I get confused. Is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for bothering the community...and the two concepts has no difference....